# Qual a melhor maneira para criar um jogo multi-plataforma?

Tags: android, ios, framework, ide

Boas,

Queria saber a melhor maneira para criar um jogo multi-plataforma (iOS, Android, ...).

Já pesquisei sobre o assunto e encrostei o Cocos2d-x, o que acham em relação a esta framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Unity3D é uma game engine completa, multiplataforma e conta com uma documentação abrangente. Você pode baixar neste site:

https://unity3d.com/pt

No Microsoft Virtual Academy eles tem uns tutoriais gratuitos. Não sei se são bons, mas se quiser ver:

https://mva.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde meu querido. A questão da engine é realmente de suma importância, tem várias no mercado, você tem que ver a que mais se adequará ao que você pretende fazer, creio que o Unity 3D seja fácil de manusear, tem a CoronaSDK que não conheço muito também. 
Porém sua pergunta ficou meio abrangente, a melhor maneira seria desde escolher o tema do jogo até a parte técnica, eu lhe diria primeiramente defina como será seu jogo, faça protótipos no papel, e não mude o que será de última hora.
Grande abraço.